# How to make a simple web service call using Breeze JS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, breeze

I'm pretty new to Breeze js. I read throw their documentation and tutorials.But couldn't really understand how to call a web service using Breezejs. I have written my web service using C# asp.net.
Any useful links which explain this would be appreciated.

Here is the Web Service Method

```
   [WebMethod]
    public Hello HelloWorld()
    {
        Hello helloObj = new Hello();
        helloObj.FirstName = "Hello";
        helloObj.LastName = "World";
        return helloObj;
    }
```

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help you better than the generic examples of the docs if you don't provide more information about your service implementation.  
Post some code sample or at least pseudo code that shows what your service looks like.

Comment: @Stephane added web service method

Answer (score 1):

I am also pretty new to Breeze, and was able to learn the basics really quickly through courses on Pluralsight. If you want to accelerate your learning curve, this is a route I'd really recommend.